# Why does syntax error occurs in a Typescript-written node_module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

```
node_modules/
  my_module/
    lib/
      index.ts
src/
  index.ts
```

I made a custom module `my_module` and wanted to use it as an external library. The codes are like below:

[src/index.ts]

```
import { hello } from 'my_module'
console.log(hello)
```

[node_modules/my_module/index.ts]

```
export const hello = "Hello"
```

My `tsconfig.json` says `"module": "commonjs", "target": "es6"`, so I thought import keywords would work nicely in Typescript files.

As I expected, the import keyword in `src/index.ts` works well, but the export keyword in `node_modules/my_module/index.ts` is an unexpected token. How can I get this problem solved?

```
export const hello = "hello"
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:431:14)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
```

Comment: It's expected that external modules are transpiled to JS before publishing. This saves some resources when they are used at least.

Comment: @estus Thank you. Is there any way to disable auto transpiling?

Comment: What do you mean? The problem is that `index.ts` in `my_module` is NOT transpiled. It should be `dist/import.js` when you import the package.

Comment: @estus That's the point I want to say. I want my every codes written in Typescript, even the custom external library. Most of blog posts about writing node modules with Typescript recommend using `tsc` and making transpiled codes into `dist/`, but I want to make my library like `tsutils`(https://github.com/ajafff/tsutils). The main codes of this library are written in Typescript. It doesn't seem to have transpiled Javscript codes

Comment: tsutils is transpiled. You can install it and check that it contains index.js.

Comment: What @estus said. The source code of tsutils is written in TypeScript, which is being transpiled before they publish it to npmjs.

Comment: estus, Ben Kauer. Thanks :) Now I need to know how I publish my custom library only with transpiled codes, keeping Typescript codes in my git repo.

Comment: @jeongmin.cha Users don't receive notifications if you don't use `@`. You don't necessary need to publish *only* transpiled code. Just transpile it. Use `tsc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the project was configured to transpile modules from `node_modules` (this is generally discouraged because this is inefficient and unneeded), it's expected that external module will be evaluated as is, and `import` keyword is not allowed in CommonJS modules.

`my_module` should be compiled before publishing, i.e. `tsc` should be executed, and `dist` should contain transpiled *.js and *.d.ts typings.

`main` in 
`my_module` package.json should specify entry point, `"main": "dist/index.js"`.

The package can optionally contain [.npmrc file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) to exclude `src` from published files, but this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I've already decided to do that right before you uploaded your answer :)

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.